# Assembly operations throw warnings during compiling

Tags: solidity, memory, assembly

Leveraging the following common string utility has been quite helpful, but would like to get rid of a warning:

`function stringToBytes32(string memory source) returns (bytes32 result) {
      assembly {
          result := mload(add(source, 32))
      }
      return result;
  }`

 But upon updating the compiler to 0.4.11, I see warnings during compilation, indicating the variable, "source"

`Unused local variable`

Anu suggestions on whether this is due to a compiler update, or the usage of 'memory' keyword?